# HowTo?: itemDetails.reduce is not a function

Tags: javascript

So, I'm attempting to `reduce` a returned graphql object (See attached image) as follows:

```html
var quantity = itemDetails.reduce((a, itemvariants) => a + itemvariants.quantity, 0);
```

I get the above mentioned error message. What am I overlooking here?

[image]

Comment: `reduce` is method on `array's` not `objects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `reduce` on the object, not the `itemVariants` array.

```
quantity = itemDetails.itemVariants.reduce((a, variant) => a + variant.quantity, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you want to reduce the items from itemVariants, not itemDetails

```
let quantity = itemDetails.itemVariants.reduce((total, variant) => total + variant.quantity, 0)
```